# Most Powerful Test and Uniformly Most Powerful Test

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Let $X$ be a single distribution with density function $f(x)$. Let the null hypothesis, $H1: f(x)=1/(pi(1+x^2))$ vs the alternate hypothesis $H2: f(x)=(1/2)e^-|x|$. Calculate the power of the most powerful test of size p.

Here being asked about the most powerful test, is it calculated in the same manner in the uniformly most powerful test?
If no, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Since there are just two simple hypotheses, what special meaning would attach to "uniformly"??

Comment: I guess my understanding of UMP test and most powerful test and specifically, the ability to differentiate between the two is not quite correct. Could you explain? @whuber

Comment: "Uniformly" means *for every distribution in the set of alternative hypotheses.*  You have only one alternative hypothesis.